# Why a charge moving parallel to magnetic field does not experience magnetic force?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, charge

As far as I know, change in electric field creates magnetic field anywhere in space. But if a charge moves parallel to the magnetic field, the magnetic force is 0, I can't imagine that. Please explain it intuitively.

Comment: Suppose it did experience a force. Which way would the force go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember, the magnetic force is always perpendicular to both the velocity and the magnetic field. As long as the velocity and the field are not parallel that gives a unique (up to a sign convention) direction. But when the velocity and the field are parallel then there are an infinite number of directions that are perpendicular to both. So intuitively, since there is no way to choose a specific direction, the magnitude must be zero since only the zero vector has an undefined direction.

Answer (score 1):

It is my understanding that a magnetic force is a relativistic distortion of an electric force.  That gets complicated.  Historically, the direction of a magnetic field was defined in such a way that it can be determined by the direction of a compass needle. Then the force equations for magnetism were formulated so that they predict the observed forces in terms of the defined field.